# Relation between magnitude of diagonal and non-diagonal entries when given information about the inverse

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, probability, matrices, inverse

Think of $\Sigma$ as a covariance matrix, or any positive semidefinite matrix. Let $A(\lambda)$ be a $n \times n$ positive semidefinite matrix with $\lambda > 0$ and the following specifications to its inverse:

$(A(\lambda))^{-1}_{jk}=\begin{cases}\Sigma_{jk}+\lambda, & j=k\\
\Sigma_{jk}+\lambda \operatorname{sgn}(A(\lambda)_{jk}), & j \neq k \text{ and }A(\lambda)_{jk} \neq 0\\
\lvert (A(\lambda))^{-1}_{jk}-\Sigma_{jk}\rvert \leq \lambda, & j\neq k \text{ and }A(\lambda)_{jk} = 0 
\end{cases}\; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; (*)$

Note that the dependency of $A(\lambda)$ is such that as $\lambda $ gets larger the matrix becomes sparser.

It is stated that by the definition of the inverse $(*)$ the diagonal entries of $A(\lambda)$ are much larger relative to its nonzero off-diagonal entries.

I do not find it clear why this would indeed be the case if we are only given the specifications of the inverse $(A(\lambda))^{-1}$? Any ideas?

Link to the paper: https://jmlr.org/papers/volume17/16-013/16-013.pdf (Top of page $7$)